# How to change the switch statement below to polymorphism in javascript and also how to access the different classes

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, polymorphism

```
let type = document.querySelector('#productType');
type.addEventListener('change', function() {

  switch (type.value) {
    case 'DVD':
      document.querySelector('.DVD').classList.add('visible');
      document.querySelector('.Furniture').classList.remove('visible');
      document.querySelector('.Book').classList.remove('visible');
      break;

    case 'Furniture':
      document.querySelector('.Furniture').classList.add('visible');
      document.querySelector('.DVD').classList.remove('visible');
      document.querySelector('.Book').classList.remove('visible');

      break;

    case 'Book':
      document.querySelector('.Book').classList.add('visible');
      document.querySelector('.Furniture').classList.remove('visible');
      document.querySelector('.DVD').classList.remove('visible');
      break;

  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array of ids and update the wanted value with a single loop

```
ids = ['DVD', 'Furniture', 'Book'];

// update
ids.forEach(id => document.querySelector(id).classList[id === value
    ? 'add'
    : 'remove'
]('visible'));
```

Comment: I would like to avoid any form of conditional statement by using polymorphism